# Return more than one value using Python - Ladon functions

Tags: python, ladon

How can we return more than one value using Python-[Ladon](http://packages.python.org/ladon/ladontype.html) functions?

Comment: what are Ladon functions? Do you mean [`lambda` functions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda)?

Comment: may be he's taking about http://packages.python.org/ladon/ladontype.html

Answer (score 1):

You can return more values by wrapping them into a list inside a class that you use as the returntype in the decorator `ladonize`.

Based on an [example in the documentation](http://packages.python.org/ladon/index.html#example-2) for ladon:

```
from ladon.ladonizer import ladonize
from ladon.types.ladontype import LadonType

class Response(LadonType):
    values = [int]

class MyService(object):
    @ladonize(int, int, rtype=Response)
    def foo(self, a, b):
        result = Response()
        result.values = [a+b, a*b]
        return result
```

Comment: thanks, it works, can we possible to return more than one dictionaries, lists etc using this method?

Comment: @user1059150 You can return an instance of a class, and inside the class there may be different datatypes. The class can have variables that are different classes itself but at the end every datatype must have a path that leads to one of the 5 primitive types. Study [this example](http://packages.python.org/ladon/index.html#example-2) from the documentation. The caller can retrieve the data from the returned instance . See http://packages.python.org/ladon/ladontype.html#ladontype-for-complex-service-types for more information.